# Injecting a Sonar analysis before an existing one

Tags: java, sonarqube

A while ago I setup [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) to scan a development project.  The scans are invoked nightly using a cronjob.  At one point I had an issue with the machine that run the cronjob and a few nightly scans were missed.  I downloaded the source code from one of the days that was missed, and completed a new Sonar scan using Sonar Runner.  As I expected the data shows up in Sonar as the most recent scan which is not what I want.  I would like to inject that scan in to a specific date so I can fill the days when the scan was not run.  I did not see an option to do this in the sonar-project.properties file.

Is there a way I can run a Sonar scan, but have the data be entered on a date of my choice rather than the current date, so it shows up in the appropriate position in my Sonar timelines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't used them but the [Sonar documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) describes the additional properties that would enable historical analysis. Specifically it's the "sonar.projectDate" property you need to set.

You haven't specified which Java build technology you're using. I've included some examples below.

Finally, have you considered setting up Jenkins to launch Sonar, instead of cron? Lots of good reasons for running Jenkins, but if you're using Maven as your build tool, the [Jenkins Sonar plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Hudson+and+Jenkins+Plugin) makes Sonar integration very easy.

## Maven example

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
mvn -Dsonar.projectDate=2012-09-01 sonar:sonar
```

## ANT example

```
ant -Dsonar.projectDate=2012-09-01 clean sonar
```

**Note:**

- This assumes you have a target called "sonar" setup to compile, test and run sonar.

Comment: I'm using sonar-runner with sonar-project.properties files.  I'll see if I can use the projectDate parameter for those files.

Comment: @TERACytE Should work the same way. Since you tagged the question as "java" I assumed you were using Maven or ANT to build your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. While there is documentation showing how to set the date of the scan, this is for retrospective scans only and can only be done in chronological order. You cannot insert a scan into an earlier point in time than the most recent one. You could delete recent scans until your retrospective date fit, I think, but you'd want to test that out before committing to it.

My advice is not to worry about it. Sonar is an approximate tool anyway, you should be able to handle the odd anomaly.

Comment: You are right. But with this technic and a little scripting it is possible to replay each sonar analysis.

Comment: I used a branch of our code reversed to an early point, added sonar config to the build script, ran an analysis on the build server, merged in a later time point, did it again and so on until I had a history. I think Sonar deletes detail from the past so you only need one example a month to get a decent trend to review.